# Why do we say 'reason enough' in some circumstances?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

*[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reason-enough)* includes these examples in the entry of *reason enough*

> *Surely that's **reason enough** to watch the show.*
> *The Sun (2016)*
> *Physical laws are **reason enough** for the Universe to have come into being spontaneously.*
> *Times, Sunday Times (2010)*
> *Anything could happen at this stage, which is **reason enough** to watch on.*
> *Times, Sunday Times (2015)*

Why is this phrase 'reason enough' written like this as if *reason* here is an adjective?

Comment: reason enough = enough reason/sufficient reason.  This kind of reverse word order can be used for stylistic/literary purposes.  Another example, "If had time enough, I would visit you".

Comment: Darn it. Why did I not think about that? Someone was asking for an explanation. And, my brain had become a brick for a moment.

Comment: You mean if you had brains enough . . . LOL!!! - Yeah I have brain farts too!

Answer (score 2):

- *Surely that's **reason enough** to watch the show.*

The “reason enough” is a type of literary device, an [inversion](https://literarydevices.net/inversion/) of a normal order of words; and in this case, –*probably*– a shortened form of

> *Surely that's **a good enough reason** to watch the show.*

*[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enough_1)* confirms my hunch and says:

> **Enough** is sometimes used after particular nouns, but this is not common:
> *Don’t ask questions – there’ll be time enough for that later.*
> *He had **reason enough** to be angry* (=he had **a good reason** to be angry).
> *I was fool enough to trust her* (=it was foolish of me to trust her).

Answer (score 1):

*Enough* as an adverb (i.e, modifying anything but a noun phrase) usually follows its head:

> I haven't practiced enough.

> It's long enough.

> They didn't try hard enough.

Only as an adjective modifying a noun phrase does it usually precede:

> Have you got enough food?

As for "why": like almost all "why" questions about language, this is unanswerable.

Comment: I think you are missing something. Long and hard are both adjective. Practiced, which is practised btw is a verb but still makes sense. To me, it seems like reason in reason enough somehow does not fit.

Comment: @Ghost - It fits perfectly. We can put 'enough' after a noun (like 'reason')  for poetic or stylistic purposes. In general use it is quite formal and old-fashioned.  _Had we but world enough and time, This coyness, lady, were no crime_

Comment: This comment and that comment are more useful that this answer. Please do not mind. They certainly satisfy my argument.

Comment: @Ghost If you think long and hard enough about it, you'll see that both can be adverbs, too.

Comment: @Ghost: [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practiced%2Cpractised&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) gave up the spelling ***practised*** well over a century ago. [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practiced%2Cpractised&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) (Colin & I are Brits) hasn't *quite* got to that position yet, but it obviously will within just a few years.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nooooo, please do not do that. I will be doomed.